# Do you know this card game (mafia themed)?

Tags: identify-this-game

I'd like to find this card game that I played a couple of years ago, the facts that I remember are the following:

- The game was played with cards, the cards being placed in 3 rows, each row representing a specific city in the US (possibly Chicago & NYC being two of them)
- Each card had a different mafia member, with 2 stats: strength and points (they might have also been divided by colour, but I can't remember)
- When two similar cards were around another, I believe that took the middle one (or ones) out of the game

Has anyone played or heard of something that has this theme and plays similarly to my description?

Comment: The game is not Mafia, it just shares that theme

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this the one? It's called "The Gang"

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much, this is the game that I've played back then and have been looking for.

Comment: @user3000239 the description was good enough to google it ;)

Comment: I've tried googling several times, and never found it.
Please teach me how to google, master

Comment: @user3000239 You just need to know where to look :) I think mentioning BGG (boardgamegeek, biggest board game database/forum) in the query did it. It cleared out all those PC mafia games flood and left only relevant stuff.